# RakNet tutorial dropping clients

Tags: c++, network-programming, client-server, raknet

sorry for the noobish question but I can't find any resources online clearly stating whether this should work or not, and all tutorials / sample code always use localhost ^^ Soooo...

I'm trying to setup a simple server / client using RakNet. I'm literally just following the first tutorial (http://www.jenkinssoftware.com/raknet/manual/tutorial.html), just trying to get the client to connect to the server and keep the connection alive for a bit.

It all works great as long as I use 127.0.0.1 or 192.168.0.XXX, I can start the server, then the client, the server detects the connection request and sends the reply to the client, the client receives the reply and prints out "connection accepted" and such, and I can exchange messages between the client and the server.

However if I try using my actual IP, the server does not seem to detect the connection request (if you look at the tutorial code, it doesn't print "incoming connection"), but the client still receives a reply from somewhere ("Our connection request has been accepted").

After this initial semi-successful connection, no more packets will be received by either server or client, and the client will inevitably get disconnected after a few seconds (I assume time out?).

Port is open on the router, and the app runs fine as long as I keep it on localhost.

So my question is: is it even possible to run a server and client on the same machine / IP which is sitting behind a router?

The RakNet documentation part about NAT punchthrough and UDP forwarding does mention no more than one client and server being able to run on the same machine, but I was under the impression that one server / one client would not be an issue?

Thanks in advance to anybody who can shed some light on this!!

Forgot to mention my firewall is disabled !